# How to create nested model from partial Rails 6

Tags: ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-6

Newbie Here!

I'm unsuccessfully trying to submit a form of a nested model.

Aim:

Verify a translation by submitting a boolean to a `reviews` model to associate whether a translation is verified or not, with translation `entry` and `user` model associated references.

```
# routes.rb
resources :entries do
   resources :reviews
end


# entry.rb
belongs_to :user
has_one :review
accepts_nested_attributes_for :review


# user.rb
has_many :entries
has_many :reviews


# review.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :entry
```

From `entry` index, pass the `entry` instance to partial, works perfect

```
# /entries/index.html.erb
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
   ...
   <%= render 'reviews/new', entry: entry %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Unsuccessfully setting up new/create form.
What happens is that the `entry` instance is well received, but I am failing to create a new model instance for `review` belonging to `entry`.

`entry.review` raises an `nil` error for `review`, while `entry` is fine when testing through browser console

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

```
# reviews/_new.html.erb
<span>
  <%= form_for entry.review do |f| %>
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
      <%= f.check_box :verified, class: "form-check-input" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
</span>
```

Another attempt was also to use just `@review` from the controller but that doesn't obey nested routes.

My controller looks like this

```
# reviews_controller.rb

def create
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])
    @review = @entry.review.build(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.save
end

private

def review_params
   params.require(:review).permit(:verified, user: current_user, entry: @entry)
end
```

Am I suppose to implement my actions in the `entries_controller`?

I have also found the tutorial [here](https://web-crunch.com/posts/lets-build-with-ruby-on-rails-blog-with-comments) useful but replication was unsuccessful.

Another StackOverflow reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231607/nested-model-form-not-submitting-everything)

I still get the error `entry.review.build` that review is nil.

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building an associated record over a `has_one` relation, instead of

```rb
@review = entry.review.build(review_params)
```

you need to use the following:

```rb
@review = entry.build_review(review_params)
```

See the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Auto-generated+methods) for more details.

> Am I suppose to implement my actions in the entries_controller?

It depends on what you're after. If you have a dedicated form for adding a new review and it is not embedded in another form for creating or updating an entry then implementing a `create` action in `ReviewsController` is the straightforward solution – in this case you should also not need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in `Entry`.

If, however, you want to be able to create or update an entry *as well as* its review using the *same form*, then you should nest the review form in the form of the entry, keep `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, and use actions in `EntriesController`. The [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) should get you started there.