# How to update @model.submodel in rails 6

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm unsuccessfully trying to update a submodel, somehow nested but getting unusual results.

**Background (Scroll down for problem):**

Update a boolean `verified` of a `reviews` model to associate whether a translation is verified or not, with translation `entry` and `user` model associated references. Details about creating a verification are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238697/how-to-create-nested-model-from-partial-rails-6/66247498#66247498)

```
# routes.rb
resources :entries do
   resources :reviews
end


# entry.rb
belongs_to :user
has_one :review
accepts_nested_attributes_for :review


# user.rb
has_many :entries
has_many :reviews


# review.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :entry
```

From `entry` index, pass the `entry` instance to the edit partial, works perfect

```
# /entries/index.html.erb
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
   ...
   <% if entry.review %>
      <%= render 'reviews/edit', entry: entry %>
   <% end %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

The `_edit.html.erb` form seems correct...

```
# reviews/_edit.html.erb
<span>
  <%= form_for([entry, entry.review]) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
      <%= f.check_box :verified, class: "form-check-input" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
</span>
```

In the browser console, the model `entry` is well assigned. And also the association `entry.review` is well assigned i.e

```
>> entry.review
=> #<Review id: 4, user_id: 1, entry_id: 19, 
     verified: false, created_at: "2021-02-18 03:43:27", 
     updated_at: "2021-02-18 14:31:15">
```

Even using the `Ruby on Rails 6` deprecated method `update_attribute` works

```
>> entry.review.update_attribute(:verified, false)
=> true
```

---

**Problem:** The `update` method in `reviews_controller.rb` executes successfully when `verified`  is `true`, but not when it's `false`

```
# reviews_controller.rb
def update
   @entry.review.update(review_params)
end

private

def review_params
   params.require(:review).permit(:verified, user: current_user, entry: @entry)
end
```

Works

```
{"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"...", 
"review"=>{"verified"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update Review"}
```

[image: Working]

but not

```
{"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"...", 
"review"=>{"verified"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Update Review"}
```

[image: not Working]

Comment: Do you have any `before_save` in your model?

Comment: No I do not have it

Comment: Change to `update!` in `@entry.review.update` to see error.

Comment: It just says `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Verified can't be blank)`. This only happens when updating `"verified"=>"0"`

Comment: Why are you assigning to your required params in your `review_params` method?

Comment: What do you mean? I use the same parameters for both create and update. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html. Is it unwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem after @yzalavin suggestion. Somehow validations were preventing the update. I do not know the association yet.

Simply adding `on: :create` allowed me o update.

```
validates_presence_of :entry_id, :user_id, :verified, on: :create
```

Comment: Ah yes. Presence validator fails when the `verified.blank?` returns `true`. Generally speaking, it should not be used for boolean values. Even as written now your create won't work with `verified: false`. For boolean columns use `validates :verified, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }` instead

Comment: So what you mean is `:verified => false` makes `verified.blank?` return true? Do you think it'll be smart just to use an integer column and work with `0` and `1` instead of a boolean type?

Comment: Ah, no, boolean columns should be used whenever it makes sense and it does make sense here. It is just that this particular validator won't work. I assume you want to test that it is not being set to nil, in which case inclusion validator is your friend.  However, to be honest, best option is to set the column to non-nullable in the database and no validation is then required.

Comment: Ah okay then. I'll try to adopt the non-nullable practice. Otherwise thanks for the input