# How to use AJAX to reload a section of page unrelated to rails controller action

Tags: ajax, erb, ruby-on-rails-6

My web app follows the structure as described in previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238697/how-to-create-nested-model-from-partial-rails-6) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66266145/how-to-update-model-submodel-in-rails-6).

See the picture below of the interface.

What I want is, when the user edits/updates verification through the `switch` icon (submit button automatically), also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66266145/how-to-update-model-submodel-in-rails-6), the `div` containing the verify/patch icon should reload/refresh to update that a translation is verified.

I could possibly have all these elements in one field, but only `moderator: true` users get to `create` and only moderators who moderated specific translations can `edit and update` the `review`.

What I tried is having

```
# entries/index.html.erb
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  ...

  <span id="show-review-<%= entry.id %>">
    <%= render 'reviews/show', entry: entry %>
  </span>

  ...

  <% if current_user.moderator %> # and other conditions
    <div id="edit-review-form-<%= entry.id %>">
      <%= render 'reviews/edit', entry: entry %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  ...
<% end %>
```

```
# reviews/_show.html.erb
# Simply if the review exists and if its true
<% if entry.review and entry.review.verified == true %>
  # blue verify icon
<% else %>
  # gray vefify icon
<% end %>
```

```
# reviews/_edit.html.erb
<%= form_for([entry, entry.review], remote: true, :authenticity_token => true) do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

```
# reviews/edit.js.erb
$('show-review-<%= entry.id %>')[0].html("<%=j render 'reviews/show', entry: entry %>")
```

---

Problem: When I submit the edit form, and `update` action in the controller is executed, I would like to reload the section of `show`. If I have my controller in this way...

```
def update
  if @entry.review.update!(review_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :partial => "reviews/show", :layout => false }
      format.js { render :template => "reviews/edit", :layout => false }
    end
  end
end
```

Having this, on `update`, my site instead redirects to a reviews URL `http://localhost:3000/entries/entry:id/reviews/review:id`

This is a nested, kinda, model. Why does is redirect to `show` when it's just a partial?

```
# rake routes
entry_reviews     GET    /entries/:entry_id/reviews(.:format)             reviews#index
                  POST   /entries/:entry_id/reviews(.:format)             reviews#create
new_entry_review  GET    /entries/:entry_id/reviews/new(.:format)         reviews#new
edit_entry_review GET    /entries/:entry_id/reviews/:id/edit(.:format)    reviews#edit
entry_review      GET    /entries/:entry_id/reviews/:id(.:format)         reviews#show
```

[image]

Comment: Probably a typo, and `reviews/edit/js.erb` is meant to be `reviews/edit.js.erb`.

Comment: Have you tried `reviews/update.js.erb`and have it render your partials just like your `edit.js.erb` does? If you try that, you can probably simplify your `respond_to` section.

Answer (score 0):

So far the temporary solution, not probably recommended but still does the job programming practice, is hiding and unhiding certain elements on specific conditions.

Upon user interaction (e.g `onClick`), unhide and hide elements while updating values that resemble the controller update. Simply simulate a refresh and update the form paths/controller actions they point to.

This will mostly work better with boolean check-box forms, [likes or dislikes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299201/how-to-implement-link-to-ajax-remote-true-respond-to-without-rendering-new-u) where variables will only alternate between two instances at max. Hence you don't have to write much javascript to handle pseudo outputs.

But still, I'm sure there's a better method for example `WebSockets` through `Action Cable`. That can probably be overkill but the closest to realtime updates. `respond_to` just doesn't seem to work